# ReactJS and Material UI TreeView: Can I use a multi-level JSON/array of objects with different names to populate the TreeView?

Tags: reactjs, json, material-ui, treeview, jsx

I have an array of objects that is multi-leveled with different names that I need to populate a TreeView component :

```
export const application_group_one = [
    {
        id: uniqueId(),
        name: "Application 1",
        organizations: [
            {
                id: uniqueId(),
                name: "Organization 1",
                artifacts: [
                    {
                        id: uniqueId(),
                        name: "Artifact 1",
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: uniqueId(),
        name: "Application 2",
        organizations: [
            {
                id: uniqueId(),
                name: "Organization 1",
                artifacts: [],
            },
        ],
    },
];

export const application_group_two = [
    {
        id: uniqueId(),
        name: "Application 3",
        organizations: [
            {
                id: uniqueId(),
                name: "Organization 1",
                artifacts: [
                    {
                        id: uniqueId(),
                        name: "Artifact 1",
                    },
                    {
                        id: uniqueId(),
                        name: "Artifact 2",
                    },
                    {
                        id: uniqueId(),
                        name: "Artifact 3",
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                id: uniqueId(),
                name: "Organization 2",
                artifacts: [
                    {
                        id: uniqueId(),
                        name: "Artifact 1",
                    },
                    {
                        id: uniqueId(),
                        name: "Artifact 2",
                    },
                    {
                        id: uniqueId(),
                        name: "Artifact 3",
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                id: uniqueId(),
                name: "Organization 3",
                artifacts: [
                    {
                        id: uniqueId(),
                        name: "Artifact 1",
                    },
                    {
                        id: uniqueId(),
                        name: "Artifacy 2",
                    },
                    {
                        id: uniqueId(),
                        name: "Artifact 3",
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                id: uniqueId(),
                name: "Organization 4",
                artifacts: [
                    {
                        id: uniqueId(),
                        name: "Artifact 1",
                    },
                    {
                        id: uniqueId(),
                        name: "Artifact 2",
                    },
                    {
                        id: uniqueId(),
                        name: "Artifact 3",
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
];
```

I'm able to output the Organizations but not the artifacts. Having varying names for each children object is giving me a hard time. I would like a TreeView that can expand as many levels as I want with differing names for the nest objects. :

```
const getTreeItemsFromData = (treeItems) => {
    return treeItems.map((treeItemData) => {
        let organizations = undefined;
        if (treeItemData.organizations && treeItemData.organizations.length > 0) {
            organizations = getTreeItemsFromData(treeItemData.organizations);
        }
        return <TreeItem key={treeItemData.id} nodeId={treeItemData.id} label={treeItemData.name} children={organizations} />;
    });
};
const DataTreeView = ({ treeItems }) => {
    return (
        <TreeView defaultCollapseIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />} defaultExpandIcon={<ChevronRightIcon />}>
            {getTreeItemsFromData(treeItems)}
        </TreeView>
    );
};

export const Tree = () => {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <DataTreeView treeItems={application_group_one} />
            <br />
            <DataTreeView treeItems={application_group_two} />
        </div>
    );
};
```